# Android, Change font size only in one app

Tags: android, font-size

Is it possible to change the default-fontsize only for one app?
So i can use the "sp" units at all my fonts?

The problem is that my customer doesn´t wan´t that his employes changes anything in the android-settings. So i am searching for a solution to change the font size in my app. Of course i could implement my own dynamic font size by programmatically changing the size of each label when the user chooses another size. But i think that is to complicated and should by the last way.

Best regards 
Yannick

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162222/android-how-to-change-app-font-size-from-code?rq=1

Comment: textview.setTextSize(int_value);

Comment: I don´t want to set the textSize on each textView! I wan´t to use the sp units. But those units only change when the user changes the android fontsize settings, but i wan´t to change them in my own app only for this app. So it´s not a duplicate!